# SwiftUI Update @State on API Async Call

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a button that is calling an JSON API to retrieve some information. The API call is the following:

```
Button(action: {
    self.result = Track().getOrderDetails()
}) {
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}
```

The variable `self.result` is a `@State` property that I was expecting to be always updated with the result from the API call. What happens is that the API is called and the State property is updated with its initialised in the function. Because the API takes to respond when the result is obtained, inside the callback API function I can print the obtained result but the Result property is not updated.

How can I handle this situations?

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: You have to assign result in API callback instead of button's action.

Comment: Thank you @Asperi. I found this great view to explain this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AahAsZ4HdVw